# How do I reference classes from another project in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans6.8

I am using NetBeans 6.8.

I have a class `ClassA` situated in `PackageA` in `JavaApplicationProject1`.

I plan to use this class in `ClassB` situated in `PackageB` in `JavaApplicationProject2` just by importing it. One option is to copy `ClassA` in `PackageB`, but I don't want to copy. How can I do this?

Comment: create a jar file of JavaApplicationProject1 and use it as dependency in JavaApplicationProject2

Comment: or use Maven. Much much easier. You would then be able to make use of your libraries using any IDE. Just a thought.

Comment: If your problem is resolved, please accept the answer that helped you most.

Comment: How do I accept the answer? I don't have sufficient reputation.

Comment: @JavaFreak https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 10):

Under `Project Properties -> Libraries -> Compile -> Add Project` you can add project dependencies. So adding `JavaApplicationProject1` as a project dependency in `JavaApplicationProject2` will do what you want. Details can be found in [this guide](https://blogs.oracle.com/roumen/entry/netbeans_quick_tip_16_using)